# grpc TCP Read Failed Error on Travis CI, where goes wrong?

Tags: travis-ci, ts-jest, grpc-node

I write some tests that involve grpc invoking and 100% pass on local machine, but on Travis CI build, it's 100% fail claiming: `TCP Read Failed`, can anyone shed some light on where goes wrong?

Detail logs here:

https://travis-ci.com/Jeff-Tian/grpc-man/builds/140791394?utm_medium=notification&utm_source=email

Thanks in advance!

### My investigations:

Firstly I doubt it's caused by the host or port I'm listening so I changed the `grpc` endpoint from `0.0.0.0:8080` to `127.0.0.1:8080`, but the result remains the same.

Comment: I see that the first error in your log says "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3003". Have you investigated that error?

Comment: Yes and I've fixed that error. But the TCP Read Failed error still remains. Will try to investigate with the macOS mirror. Because the tests runs smoothly on my macOS, while on travis CI it's default to use linux

Comment: Yes and I've fixed that error. But the TCP Read Failed error still remains. Will try to investigate with the macOS mirror. Because the tests runs smoothly on my macOS, while on travis CI it's default to use linux